# using group by with condition in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two situations in my query , One where I need to use group by clause and other where i do Not want to use group by

So in below query If Name = Map .. then use group by..like this  (Means show Only distinct Id's)

```
      select max(start_time),id,name from workitem where ( NAME = 'Map' or NAME = 'Validate') group by id,name;
```

But if in the above query when Name Not equal 'Map' then DO NOT use group by..like this  (Means show all id's even duplicates)

```
       select start_time,id,name from workitem where ( NAME = 'Map' or NAME = 'Validate');
```

How can i achieve this with one query

Comment: Can you group by name when you aren't selecting it?

Comment: Your requirement to combine the two queries doesn't make much sense on the surface. One is selecting the maximum start time for each id, the other one every start time for each id. Why would one query want to return both sets, with nothing to distinguish what is what? Perhaps if you gave an example expected output, that would clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  select max(start_time),id 
  from workitem where ( NAME = 'Map' or NAME = 'Validate') 
  group by id,name
  UNION ALL
  select start_time,id 
  from workitem 
  where NAME <> 'Map';
```